# Add an "Interesting" tab to the "Questions" section, and default to it

Tags: feature-request

When I click on the Questions button in the new navbar, I'm redirected to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions` which defaults to a `New`  tab, where all the new questions are shown, regardless of the technologies.

By contrast, when you click on the logo in the navbar, just to the left of the Questions button, it redirects to `http://stackoverflow.com/` where it defaults to an `Interesting` tab that shows questions that are more relevant to me.

This is a bit confusing, I would expect the Questions button to also show me the interesting questions by default. There's really no reason to show all the questions, I'm much more likely to be interested in (and also be able to answer to) questions that are appear in the `Interesting`  section since they are about technologies/tags that I know about.

Would it be possible to add a new tab to the `/questions`  page, called `Interesting` , that shows the same question that you see on the home page?

I really like the new navbar and find myself using the Questions buttons a lot more, only to realize that it shows me irrelevant questions & answers, so I have to click on the logo to go where I want.

Comment: Would removing the questions tab thus making more room to have the fullsize logo solve the same problem?

Comment: The downside i see is, as a new user, "Interesting" tab algorithm wouldn't have a whole lot to go on to filter down to interesting results, right? What happens currently on the home page for a new user?

Comment: @KevinB Yes, it would solve the same problem for me, but from a usability point of view, it might be better to have the Questions tab instead. Clicking on the logo is second nature for a power user, but for a lot of regular users it's definitely not as obvious as button/tab.